# Titan + Tinkerpop extremly slow read

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cassandra, titan, tinkerpop

My setup is: Java 1.7, Tinkerpop 2.6, Titan 0.5.3, Cassandra 2.1.2 and Easticsearch 1.4.2.

My problem is that I have extremely slow reads. In my test code I'm inserting only one Vertex with one property. This takes 5 ms. Then I try to read this Vertex again. This takes 1500 ms. Why is the reading 300 times slower?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
long d1 = new Date().getTime();

String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
Vertex customer = g.addVertex();
customer.setProperty("somethingnew", id);
g.commit();

long d2 = new Date().getTime();
long d3 = 0;;

Iterable<Vertex> its = g.query().has("somethingnew", id).vertices();        
for (Vertex vert : its) {
    if (vert.getProperty("somethingnew").toString().equals(id)) {
        d3 = new Date().getTime();
    }
}

System.err.println( "Insert took [ms]:" + (d2 - d1));
System.err.println( "Read took [ms]:" + (d3 - d2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into reading about indexes